# How to fold all open editors in visual studio code using a script

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to be able to create/write a command to fold all code in all open editors within visual studio code.

I believe I am very close.

I am using the "script commands" extension written by [Marcel J. Kloubert](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vs-script-commands)

When I use the following script with 7 or so open editors in a single group. I achieve the following:

1. The open editor (at the time of execution) has its code folded
2. VSC will loop over the open editors
3. No other editor has its code folded

The script I am using:

```
// Fold all code in all open editors.
function execute(args) {

    // Obtain access to vscode
    var vscode = args.require('vscode');

    // Set number of open editors... (future: query vscode for number of open editors)
    var numOpenEditor = 20;


    // Loop for numOpenEditor times
    for (var i = 0; i <= numOpenEditor; i++){

        // Fold the current open editor
        vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.foldAll');

        // Move to the next editor to the right
        vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.nextEditor');

        // Loop message
        var statusString = 'Loop ->' + i

        // print message
        vscode.window.showErrorMessage(statusString);
    }

}

// Script Commands must have a public execute() function to work.
exports.execute = execute;
```

I have made an interesting observation, when I use the above script with 7 or so open editors **with two groups or more.** Something about switching to a new group will allow the command `editor.foldAll` to work. Note, that if a group has multiple editors, the only editor to fold its code is the open editor in the group. Thus, all other editors will not fold.

I also thought that maybe... the script needed to slow down, so I added a function to pause on every iteration. This did not turn out to work either.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make this function async and wait for the executeCommand calls to complete before moving on:

```
// Fold all code in all open editors.
async function execute(args) {

    // Obtain access to vscode
    var vscode = args.require('vscode');

    // Set number of open editors... (future: query vscode for number of open editors)
    var numOpenEditor = 5;


    // Loop for numOpenEditor times
    for (var i = 0; i <= numOpenEditor; i++) {

        // Fold the current open editor
        await vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.foldAll');

        // Move to the next editor to the right
        await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.nextEditor');

        // Loop message
        var statusString = 'Loop ->' + i

        // print message
        vscode.window.showErrorMessage(statusString);
    }

}

// Script Commands must have a public execute() function to work.
exports.execute = execute;
```